# c++ initialize 2d vector with a new class ; default value change

Tags: c++, class, vector, 2d, default

I would like to initialize a 2d vector but I keep getting an error message

if I write this code

```
unsigned long size = 101;
double initialmPo = 63;

std::vector<std::vector<Soil> > matrixPotential(
              size, std::vector<Soil>(size));
```

I do not have a problem 
but if I write this code

```
    std::vector<std::vector<Soil> > matrixPotential(
              size, std::vector<Soil>(size, initialmPo));
```

I get the message of

```
no matching constructor for initialization of  std::vector< Soil >
```

I would like to have a 101*101 vector and inside of vector is the value(number) of 63.

And that is my class Soil

```
class Soil
{
public:
    Soil();
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;
    double D;
};

#endif // SOIL_H
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] by adding the required `#include`s and the main function.

Comment: When selecting among overloaded template functions (in this case the constructors for `vector<Soil>` the compiler does not look at conversions. There is no constructor that takes a `double` as its second argument. Either change the type of `initialmPo` to `int` or cast it to an `int` in your code.

Comment: [Works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YZMDDnlzCyFQFQ41).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because `initialmPo` is not a valid `Soil` instance. The [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector` you need is

```
explicit vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());     (until C++11)

         vector( size_type count,    
                 const T& value,
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());     (since C++11)
```

For this to work you should pass the desired `Soil` element as a second parameter. In your class, you should define a constructor that takes care of initializing the fields with the desired value(s). Or you should eliminate the parameterless constructor and opt for an [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Example (with constructor)

```
#include <vector>

class Soil
{
public:
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;
    double D;
    Soil(double in) : A{in}, B{in}, C{in}, D{in} { }
};


int main()
{
  unsigned long size = 101;
  double initialmPo = 63;
  Soil s(initialmPo);
  std::vector<std::vector<Soil> > matrixPotential(
              size, std::vector<Soil>(size, s));

  return 0;
}
```

See it [live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0bc2e2f6c2d7587)

Example (with aggregate initialization)

```
#include <vector>

class Soil
{
public:
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;
    double D;
};


int main()
{
  unsigned long size = 101;
  double initialmPo = 63;
  Soil s{initialmPo, initialmPo, initialmPo, initialmPo};
  std::vector<std::vector<Soil> > matrixPotential(
              size, std::vector<Soil>(size, s));

  return 0;
}
```

See it [live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e95a1030558b84b)

Comment: can you reproduce his issue? I can't. So how are you able to provide an answer?

Comment: @MarekR The issue is in the second example of the question, which [does not compile](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c996ebc1b98527aa)

Comment: Ok now I see the problem :) Thanks.

Comment: At the second example, at the line, `Soil s{initialmPo, initialmPo, initialmPo, initialmPo}; ` i get an error again no matching constructor for initialization of Soil

Comment: but from the first example, i do not see any errors!!! thank you so much! and also thank you for your kindness and good explanation! thankyou :)

Comment: @Kang_HM The code compiles on Coliru, see the link. You should probably double check, and also note that aggregate initialization requires c++11 or higher.